# how to parse for more than 4 positions

Tags: sql

I have a funny case where a piece of data needed, is actually embedded in a column of data looking something like this:
note that is a shop with strong legacy mess still in place.

adlu201008270919_3.zip the date is what i need and is embedded.

I have code to do this here:

```
AND CAST(SUBSTRING(M.MDS_FILE,5,4) + '-' +  SUBSTRING(M.MDS_FILE,9,2) + '-' +   SUBSTRING(M.MDS_FILE,11,2)  as datetime)
```

But now I find out that where you have here 'adlu' that is 4 pos. It can be 3 or 2 or 1.
So I have to code for that I have come up with this: but it's not compiling:

```
AND CASE WHEN          WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING(M.MDS_FILE,5,4) + '-' +  SUBSTRING(M.MDS_FILE,9,2) + '-' +   SUBSTRING(M.MDS_FILE,11,2)  as datetime) 
ELSE WHEN OEN.LENGTH(S.FACILITY_KEY) = 3 THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(M.MDS_FILE,4,4) + '-' +  SUBSTRING(M.MDS_FILE,8,2) + '-' +   SUBSTRING(M.MDS_FILE,10,2)  as datetime)
ELSE WHEN OEN.LENGTH(S.FACILITY_KEY) = 2 THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(M.MDS_FILE,3,4) + '-' +  SUBSTRING(M.MDS_FILE,7,2) + '-' +   SUBSTRING(M.MDS_FILE,9,2)  as datetime)
ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING(M.MDS_FILE,2,4) + '-' +  SUBSTRING(M.MDS_FILE,6,2) + '-' +   SUBSTRING(M.MDS_FILE,8,2)  as datetime) END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CASE` requires an evaluation.   Your first statement just says `WHEN(a bunch of conversions)` but there's never an evaluation (`=, <, >` etc).

I'm assuming you want that to be `AND CASE WHEN OEN.LENGTH(s.FACILITY_KEY) = 4 THEN ...`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `CASE` statement based of `S.FACILITY_KEY`, I would use `PATINDEX` to dynamically find the start position of the date string that you're looking for:

```
DECLARE 
    @TestValue1 VARCHAR(50),
    @TestValue2 VARCHAR(50),
    @TestValue3 VARCHAR(50),
    @TestValue4 VARCHAR(50)

SET @TestValue1 = 'adlu201008270919_3.zip'
SET @TestValue2 = 'adl201008270919_3.zip'
SET @TestValue3 = 'ad201008270919_3.zip'
SET @TestValue4 = 'a201008270919_3.zip'

SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@TestValue1, PATINDEX('%[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', @TestValue1), 8) AS DATETIME)
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@TestValue2, PATINDEX('%[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', @TestValue2), 8) AS DATETIME)
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@TestValue3, PATINDEX('%[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', @TestValue3), 8) AS DATETIME)
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@TestValue4, PATINDEX('%[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', @TestValue4), 8) AS DATETIME)
```